# i want make registration date and expire date php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

i have developed ads website

but i have problem, i want make period from registration date

and when this period is end the ad will disappear

i put in insert query

example:

```
//i put in insert query for reg_date this 

'insert into ads (reg_date) values (NOW());
```

> ## row1 --- reg_date ==== 13/11/2012
>
> ## row2 --- exp_date ==== 1 month

i want after one month this ad will disapper or not active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT INTO ads (reg_date, exp_date) VALUES (now(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))`

Comment: thx --- i need to know the type of the rows (reg and exp date) in mysql
and iwant alarm me 7 days before the end of period :)

Comment: NOW() will return a [datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) but you could store the values as strings, ints, datetimes. depends on how you plan to use the dates.

Comment: thx i did it (date) and it working well - now i need to know how alarm me when the period well be end (i want the idea) :)

Answer (score 1):

Write a cron file to get exp_date to alarm 7 days before the end of period and schedule this cron for daily run. Query to get expiration date before seven days is below.

SELECT * FROM ads WHERE DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) = exp_date;